# How to tell ReSharper to use C# 2.0 spec in code issues?

Tags: resharper-5.0

I've begun using ReSharper and really enjoy it. However I have a project which must use C# 2.0 specs. Is there anyway to get ReSharper to base its suggestions off of the 2.0 spec? I keep getting these suggestions to convert things to var and to use lambda expressions, which would be great, but I can't take advantage of them.

I'm using VS2010, Resharper 5

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out, it is sort of hidden. If you click on the Solutions Explorer, select the project and then navigate to the properties pane below that, it lets you select "Language Level." After I set it to C# 2.0 it worked wonderfully!